# Cannot Insert Update Activity

Tags: apex, trigger

My organization has a managed package that is causing failures on every update to all records in our database.

```
Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: 
LID.ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.LID.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 312, column 1 
Trigger.LID.ContactTrigger: line 7, column 1. 
You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.


---The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: 
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: LID.ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: 
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.LID.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 312, column 1 
Trigger.LID.ContactTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up 
ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: LID.ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.LID.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 312, column 1 Trigger.LID.ContactTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.---The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: LID.ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.LID.SObjectDomain.triggerHandler: line 312, column 1 Trigger.LID.ContactTrigger: line 7, column 1. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
```

I am struggling to understand how to get rid of this error.

Comment: so is LID the managed package or part of your org's custom apex triggers?

Comment: @cropredy Yes - It is a LinkedIn Sales Navigator managed package